# c++ video compression library that supports many different compression algorithms?

Tags: c++, video, graphics, compression, video-streaming

For a scientific project i need to compress video data. The video however doesn't contain natural video and the quality characteristics of the compression will be different than for natural footage (preservation of hard edges for example is more important than smooth gradients or color correctness).

I'm looking for a library that can be easily integrated in an existing c++ project and that let's me experiment with different video compression algorithms.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). It is the the most mature open source tool for video compression and decompression. It comes with a command line tool, and with libraries for codecs and muxers/demuxers that can be statically or dynamically linked.

Answer (score 0):

As satuon already answered, FFmpeg is the go-to solution for all things multimedia. However, I just wanted to suggest an easier path for you than trying to hook your program up to its libraries. It would probably be far easier for you to generate a sequence of raw RGB images within your program, dump each out to disc (perhaps using a ridiculously simple [format like PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html)), and then use FFmpeg from the command like to compress them into a proper movie.

This workflow might cut down on your prototyping and development time.

As for the specific video codec you will want to use, you have a plethora of options available to you. One of the most important considerations will be: Who needs to be able to play your video and what software will they have available?